# Detecting touches on nodes built programmatically? Cannot access node name correctly?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I solved one of my other questions about reducing repeating code by building a buildCharacter method like this -

```
 func buildCharacter(name:String, height: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, position: CGPoint, zPosition: CGFloat) {
    let animatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: name)
    var animationFrames: [SKTexture] = []
    
    let numImages = animatedAtlas.textureNames.count
    for i in 1...numImages {
        let textureName = "\(name)\(i)"
        
        animationFrames.append(animatedAtlas.textureNamed(textureName))
    }
    
    animatedCharacter = animationFrames
    let firstFrameTexture = animatedCharacter[0]
    builtCharacter = SKSpriteNode(texture: firstFrameTexture)
    builtCharacter.size.height = height
    builtCharacter.size.width = width
    builtCharacter.position = position
    builtCharacter.zPosition = zPosition
    builtCharacter.name = name
    
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addChild(builtCharacter)
    
   }
```

I then call them on a per scene basis like so -

```
buildCharacter(name: "Bear", height: 370, width: 370, position: CGPoint(x: 295, y: 25), zPosition: 10)

buildCharacter(name: "Cat", height: 240, width: 240, position: CGPoint(x: 134, y: -38), zPosition: 12)
```

This works great at building and adding them to scenes, however I am struggling to detect touches and then animate them. My previous TouchesBegan looked like this -

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    if let touch = touches.first {
           let location = touch.location(in: self)

           var closest:CGFloat?
            let nodes = nodes(at:location)
            for node in nodes as [SKNode] {
               if let sprite = node as? SKSpriteNode {
                   // Calculate the distance from the node to the touch
                   let dx = location.x - node.position.x
                   let dy = location.y - node.position.y
                   let distance = dx*dx + dy*dy
                   // Find the closest
                   if closest == nil || distance < closest! {
                       closest = distance
                       selectedNode = sprite

                   }
               }
           }
       }

switch selectedNode {
        case bear:
            
            if builtCharacter.hasActions() {
                SoundEngine.shared.stopBackgroundMusic(fadeOut: false)
                stopAllAnimation()
            } else {
                SoundEngine.shared.playBackgroundMusic("blueRail.aif", loop: false)
                startAllAnimation()
            }
        case cat:
            
            if cat.hasActions() {
                SoundEngine.shared.stopBackgroundMusic(fadeOut: false)
                stopAllAnimation()
            } else {
                SoundEngine.shared.playBackgroundMusic("cluckOldHen.aif", loop: false)
                animateCat()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                    self.startAllAnimation()
                   }

            }
```

So basically I am struggling to access the node name? I tried builtCharacter.name and could not figure it out...I m thinking I can either do something different in TouchesBegan or add something to the buildCharacter method?

I'm aware I can do this in the storyboard quite easily and that is my backup plan - just trying to learn a lil more with this approach. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your `switch selectedNode` statement, don't you need to do the switch on the selected node's name and put the cases: bear and cat, in quotes? Are bear and cat strings or are they enums that are not in the code you supplied?

Comment: They are strings - so if I put them as the case they error out because selectedNode is a SKSpriteNode...I tried casting selectedNode as a string too - also errors...but I feel like it is something in that section too.

Comment: You have to switch on the selected node's name: `selectedNode.name` with cases for  "bear" or "cat" because they are strings. The name is an optional so you may not be able to switch directly on the name. In your current code you are switching on the selected node. SpriteKit has no bear and cat sprite nodes so the code in those cases will never execute.

Comment: That makes sense - I tried switching on 'selectNode.name' with the string cases and yeah it does not work. I'm not sure what else to switch on?  Is it possible to create a bear and cat sprite node within the buildCharacters method instead of just having builtCharacter nodes?

Comment: `selectedNode.name` isn't going to work directly because the `name` property of `SKNode` is an optional. You would need an `if let` statement on the name and switch on that. The name is the only direct way to determine the kind of sprite that was touched. The only alternative is to create your own struct or class for the character along with an enum for the type of character: bear, cat, or whatever. The struct/class has properties for the enum and the sprite node. Use the enum to determine the type of character that was touched.

Comment: Yup- that worked! Thank you!! Still wrapping my head around optionals...

Comment: this does bring up a add'l issue - how would you run an action a node built like this? Before I was able to do `bear.run(someAction)` but now I'm not sure how to target a specific node for an action?

Comment: You should ask a new question for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty figured it out with @Mark Szymczyk's help. Since the name property of an SKNode is optional, I had to run the switch in an if let statement and switch on the non optional name

```
 if let nodeName = selectedNode.name {
            switch nodeName {
                    case "Bear" :
                        print("Bear touched")
                    case "Cat":
                        print("Cat touched")
                    default:
                        print("No node touched")
```

Now I can access the node name and detect touches.